# Is recursion used in practice to improve performance of AI systems?

Tags: math

Is there any methods by which artificial intelligence use recursion(s) to solve a certain issue or to keep up working and calculating?

Comment: Can you clarify the phrase 'keep up working and calculating'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my knowledge, recursion does not play a strong role in the definition of modern AI techniques, although it does feature used in Lovasz's definition of 'Local Search' and Kurzweil is [certainly an advocate](http://www.kurzweilai.net/a-formula-for-intelligence-the-recursive-paradigm).

Recursion can be seen as an elegant 'architectural factorization' - building complexity by combining the results of smaller, similar patterns previously encountered. Computationally, [recursion can always be converted into iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931762/can-every-recursion-be-converted-into-iteration) so this form of elegance is really mainly of use in helping to make designs more comprehensible.

GOFAI algorithms that were traditionally defined using recursion include depth- and breath- first search and means-ends analysis (used in Newell and Simon's General Problem Solver).

With respect to performance, while many functions can be very economically *defined* using recursion, the naive version of such definitions can be inefficient.

[This page gives](http://rayhightower.com/blog/2014/04/12/recursion-and-memoization/) an example in which recursive version of the Fibonacci function, which has asymptotic execution time $n^{1.6}$, which is reduced to $n$ by the use of memoization.

Comment: It's important to note that some languages like Prolog use recursion as one of the main methods of handling parse trees - this is considered powerful when it comes to handling NLP and applications like Watson make use of this property.